# Regex to match string at the starting of text

Tags: regex

I have the following RegEx https://www.regex101.com/r/ZvXQmI/2 which would match any word starting with @. It works pretty good however, it doesn't match the string at the start of the text. Appreciate if you could help me on this. Also, RegEx shows it took 1029 steps. If this can be reduce to improve performance, highly appreciate that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word-boundaries.

```
\B(?<word>@[a-zA-Z]\w+)\b
```

https://www.regex101.com/r/ZvXQmI/4

Effectively, \B matches at any position between two word characters as well as at any position between two non-word characters. (required to exclude the domain, where @ is preceded by a word-character)

Voila, 42 steps, same result.

Comment: The `\b` isn't really necessary, because `\w+` will always capture up until a word boundary.

Comment: @4castle right, that takes it down to 37 steps. :-)

Comment: you're right @4castle. I removed the \b and its reduced to 37 steps. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to *match any word starting with @* you can do:

```
(@\w+)
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/2K1p0l/1)

That does it in 32 steps. (Or use a word boundary `\B(@\w+)` if you want more specificity)

If you want to keep your regex and match the word at the beginning, you can add `^` for the beginning of the string like so:

```
(?:>|\s+|^)(?<word>@[a-zA-Z]\w+)(<|\s+)?
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/aoVgxT/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(?<word>@[a-zA-Z]\w+)(<|\s+)?
```

Demo: https://www.regex101.com/r/ZvXQmI/3

If you just want words that start with `@`, You could use something simpler

```
@[a-zA-Z]\w+
```

Comment: @4castle Yeah to some extent. I removed it.